# MPI Fortran WTIME not working well

Tags: parallel-processing, fortran, mpi, hpc

I am coding using Fortran MPI and I need to get the run time of the program. Therefore I tried to use the WTIME() function but I am getting some strange results.

Part of the code is like this:

```
    program heat_transfer_1D_parallel
    implicit none   
    include 'mpif.h'

    integer myid,np,rc,ierror,status(MPI_STATUS_SIZE)

    integer                       :: N,N_loc,i,k,e !e = number extra points (filled with 0s)
    real                          :: time,tmax,start,finish,dt,dx,xmax,xmin,T_in1,T_in2,T_out1,T_out2,calc_T,t1,t2
    real,allocatable,dimension(:) :: T,T_prev,T_loc,T_loc_prev

    call MPI_INIT(ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_SIZE(MPI_COMM_WORLD,np,ierror)
    call MPI_COMM_RANK(MPI_COMM_WORLD,myid,ierror)
...
    t1 = MPI_WTIME()    
    time = 0.
    do while (time.le.tmax)
...
    end do
...
    call MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD,ierror)
    t2 = MPI_WTIME()        
    call MPI_FINALIZE(ierror)   

    if(myid.eq.0) then
        write(*,"(8E15.7)") T(1:N-e)
        write(*,*)t2
        write(*,*)t1
    end if
```

And the output value for t1 and t2 is the same and a very big: 1.4240656E+09
Any ideas why? Thank you so much.

Comment: The difference t2-t1 is 0. Exactly: 0.0000000E+00

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.mpich.org/static/docs/v3.1.3/www3/MPI_Wtime.html): Return value: Time in seconds since an arbitrary time in the past. They didn't specify how far back ;-) Only t2-t1 is meaningful here...

Also, the return value of `MPI_Wtime()` is *`double precision`*!  `t1` and `t2` are declared as single precision floats.

Answer (score 6):

Building on the answer from Alexander Vogt, I'd like to add that many Unix implementations of `MPI_WTIME` use `gettimeofday(2)` (or similar) to retrieve the system time and then convert the returned `struct timeval` into a floating-point value. Timekeeping in Unix is done by tracking the number of seconds elapsed since the Epoch (00:00 UTC on 01.01.1970). While writing this, the value is 1424165330.897136 seconds and counting.

With many Fortran compilers, `REAL` defaults to single-precision floating point representation that can only hold 7.22 decimal digits, while you need at least 9 (more if subsecond precision is needed). The high-precision time value above becomes 1.42416538E9 when stored in a `REAL` variable. The next nearest value that can be represented by the type is 1.4241655E9. Therefore you cannot measure time periods shorter than (1.4241655 - 1.42416538).10<sup>9</sup> or 120 seconds.

Use double precision.